# Issue while compiling a hello world class using Javassist

Tags: java, javassist

I am using Javassist to write a HelloWorld class with main method. When I compile , I get an error as below.  I am not sure what's wrong with String[] args in the main method ?

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] syntax error near "ng[] args)"
at javassist.CtNewMethod.make(CtNewMethod.java:78)
at javassist.CtNewMethod.make(CtNewMethod.java:44)
```

This is my code

```
 public void createClass() {
    ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass ct = cp.makeClass("HelloClass");
    try {
        CtMethod m = CtNewMethod.make("public void sayHello() { System.out.println(\"Hello     World\");}",ct);
        ct.addMethod(m);

       String str="public static void main(String[] args)";
        CtMethod n = CtNewMethod.make(str,ct);
        n.setBody("HelloClass a = new HelloClass();a.sayHello();");
        ct.addMethod(n);
        ct.writeFile();

    } catch (CannotCompileException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
     JavaAssistExample inject = new JavaAssistExample();
    inject.createClass();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the javadoc for [`CtNewMethod`](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtNewMethod.html) states

> The source code must include not only the method body but the whole declaration

It must therefore contain the `{}`, like

```
String str = "public static void main(String[] args){}";
```

However, two more things will give you problems.

First, you don't have a default (or a no arg) constructor. Add one

```
ct.addConstructor(CtNewConstructor.defaultConstructor(ct));
```

Second, the [`CtMethod#setBody(..)`](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtBehavior.html#setBody%28java.lang.String%29) method completely replaces the method body. So you can't do what you are doing. If you want all of those calls, you'll need to put them together

```
n.setBody("{HelloClass a = new HelloClass();a.sayHello();}");
```